# Display PDF in IFrame when button is clicked in JSF

Tags: jsf, pdf, iframe

I already coded one but it opens a new tab, what I want is to display the pdf inside the Iframe (the same page where the user inputted the data) when a command button is clicked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rendered` attribute to render content conditionally.

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="Show PDF" action="#{bean.showPdf}" />
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.pdfUrl}">
    <iframe src="#{bean.pdfUrl}"></iframe>
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```
public void showPdf() {
    pdfUrl = "/context/filename.pdf";
}
```